# Multiple loops with the same logic just different fields

Tags: java

I have multiple loops using the same logic. The only change is the field!

```
MyObjectList.stream()
        .map(MyObject::getValue1)
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

I have the same logic for getValue2, getValue3, and so on.

How can I make it generic? Like having one method/class that will deal with all these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
public <T, R> String join(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, R> mapper) {
    return collection.stream()
               .map(mapper)
               .map(String::valueOf)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare `R`, and you should make it static, so: `public static <T, R> String join(...`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. From the case above, R is not needed. I had change from Function<T, R> to Function<T, String>

Comment: If the mapper result is a `String`, there would be no need for `.map(String::valueOf)`, now would there? Which means that `R` is most likely *not* `String`.